# How do I turn an 88 byte ECDSA public key into a 65 byte uncompressed or 33 byte compressed key for use with bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin, ecdsa

In my situation my private key is in an HSM. I cannot access it for use with the various bitcoin golang libraries. Most of the functions require the private key "in-use". Although in my case, I can generate the signature later used for signing with an HSM API, I can't use the remainder of the library because of this issue.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm

Hence the question, How do I turn an 88 byte ECDSA public key into a 65 byte uncompressed or 33 byte compressed key for use with bitcoin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say, `88 byte ECDSA public key`, I think what you are actually referring to is a 65-byte uncompressed public key, which has been base64-encoded.  Base64 encoding requires 4 characters for every 3 bytes encoded, then the string's length is padded up to a multiple of 4.  S0, base64-encoding 65 bytes would result in a base64-encoded string 88 characters long.

Assuming your are given a base64-encoded string 88 characters in length, like so:

```
 BFCGOtZKh66KL+g8GvGoQDy1P1PkhthRHa2KBIh+WyNSLNRwJDRTopn6nncjdxYQOrwRod84hV7W8u4YfpxYK6Y=
```

You can convert it to hexadecimal using the following command:

```
echo -n 'BFCGOtZKh66KL+g8GvGoQDy1P1PkhthRHa2KBIh+WyNSLNRwJDRTopn6nncjdxYQOrwRod84hV7W8u4YfpxYK6Y=' | base64 -d | xxd -p
```

which produces:

```
0450863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b23522cd470243453a299fa9e77237716103abc11a1df38855ed6f2ee187e9c582ba6
```

As you can see, this is 65 bytes (each pair of hexadecimal characters represents one byte).  The first hexadecimal character is `04` (to signify a 65-byte uncompressed public key), followed by the 32-byte X value, followed by the 32-byte Y value.

---

**Edit**

Thank you for your comment.  This is helpful.

The hex string that you provided is:

```
3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a034200049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec
```

The first 23 bytes are just ASN.1 stuff.  The remaining 65 bytes contain the uncompressed public key.

```
049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec
```

The first hexadecimal character is `04` (to signify a 65-byte uncompressed public key), followed by the 32-byte X value, followed by the 32-byte Y value.  So, the X and Y values are:

```
X:  9bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1da
Y:  ad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec
```

To check if this is correct, we can verify that the point (X, Y) is on the secp256k1 curve, using the short python script below, based on the [definition of the secp256k1 curve](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1).  The script prints `True` if the point is on the curve, and `False` if not:

```
a=0
b=7
p=0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
x=0x9bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1da
y=0xad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec

ispoint=(y * y - x * x * x - a * x - b) % p == 0 
print(ispoint)
```

Running the script prouduces:

```
True
```

*As always, when playing with Bitcoin addresses, be sure that you have the correct private key corresponding with your Bitcoin address before sending a large amount of Bitcoin to this address.  You might want to send a small amount of Bitcoin to the address first, and check that you can then spend these coins (using the private key to sign the transaction), before sending a large amount of Bitcoin to this address.

Comment: I did a bit more research and learned that the API that returns the public key returns it asa ASN.1 DER encoding of a BIP-32 derived public key based on the chainPath.

When I print it out the bytes as a hex string the value is: 

3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a034200049bb8e80670371f45508b5f8f59946a7c4dea4b3a23a036cf24c1f40993f4a1daad1716de8bd664ecb4596648d722a4685293de208c1d2da9361b9cba74c3d1ec

Does your response still apply to ANS.1 DER format? I would then need to some how decode ANS.1 DER format back to ECDSA decoded base64?

Thanks

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your comment.  This is helpful.  Please see the edit I made to my answer.